# Add future time to date and compare

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I apologize if this question has been asked already but I couldn't find it for my problem.

I have seen this but am not sure what the number it returns represents:  `Date() * 1 * 10 * 1000`

I'd like to set a future moment in time, and then compare it to the current instance of `Date()` to see which is greater.  It could be a few seconds, a few minutes, a few hours or a few days in the future.

Here is the code that I have:

```
var futureMoment = new Date() * 1 *10 * 1000;
console.log('futureMoment = ' + futureMoment);

var currentMoment = new Date();
console.log('currentMoment = ' + currentMoment);

if ( currentMoment < futureMoment) {
    console.log('currentMoment is less than futureMoment.  item IS NOT expired yet');
}
else {
    console.log('currentMoment is MORE than futureMoment.  item IS expired');
}
```

Comment: More a comment, if you can add a js library to your project you may be interested in http://www.datejs.com/ it can help you for this things or compare your results agains it's results.

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of that site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript date is based on the number of milliseconds since the Epoch (1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC).

Therefore, to calculate a future date you add milliseconds.

```
var d = new Date();
var msecSinceEpoch = d.getTime();  // date now
var day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 24hr * 60min * 60sec * 1000msec
var futureDate = new Date(msecSinceEpoc + day);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

```
var futureMoment = new Date() * 1 *10 * 1000;
```

becomes

```
var now = new Date();
var futureMoment = new Date(now.getTime() + 1 *10 * 1000);
```

I think you mean to add time. Not multiply it.

Comment: hmm, that gives me the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object Mon Feb 10 2014 19:49:31 GMT-0600 (CST)10000 has no method 'getTime' 

Here's a fiddle with it: http://jsfiddle.net/Ax3F6/

Comment: It was the line before causing a Type issue. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with time, there is a lot of tools to choose.
Try [moment library](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

Used following code to compare selected date time with current date time

```
var dt = "Thu Feb 04 2016 13:20:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"; //this date format will receive from input type "date"..
function compareIsPastDate(dt) {    
    var currDtObj = new Date();
    var currentTime = currDtObj.getTime();

    var enterDtObj = new Date(dt);
    var enteredTime = enterDtObj.getTime();

    return (currentTime > enteredTime);   
}
```